# Sequence Diagrams and Class Diagrams: Which object should functions be part of?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

So I'm in the process of a Software Engineering coursework assignment involving sequence diagrams. It's one of these things where it's been covered at a pace so fast, I'm sort of left to fill in the blanks, but not entirely sure what's going on.

Anyhow, say I have object A and object B. Say A powers on B. Then we would have a function "powerOn()" with an arrow pointing from A to be, correct?

Now, would this function be a function of B, or a function of A? I'm thinking it would be a function of B, and A calls that function, as there could be another way, for object C for example, to power on B, and you surely wouldn't have a seperate function for each, you would just have both call the function on B. Is this correct?

In more general terms, is any function from A to B, always a function of the object the arrow is pointing to in that case?

i.e. Would they be included in the class diagram as a function in the object A, or in B?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that class A knows about existence of B objects and has references to them is shown by association A->B.

The fact, that A instance can call some function of one of these B instances is to be shown not by Class diagram, but by far more thorough Composite Structure Diagram. In Class diagram you can mention it by a comment only.

The problem of choosing: if to make the function changing the state of B instance the part of B or A class is NOT UML question, it is OOP question. Yes, more often it is better to put the function into B, for incapsulation and isolation, for otherwards you have to allow A to work with states of B directly, what is bad OOP behaviour. (but we don't know if you are working in OOP at all, so it is impossible to say you MUST do it)

Answer (score 0):

About your questions:

> > Then we would have a function "powerOn()" with an arrow pointing from A to be, correct?

Yes.

> > Now, would this function be a function of B, or a function of A?

A function of `B`, but, will be executed from a function in `A`

> > you would just have both call the function on `B`. Is this correct?

Each class will have code that executes the same function on `B`.

> > Would they be included in the class diagram as a function in the object `A`, or in `B`?

In `B`.

Now, let's have a real world example.

Let's have a class called `FastFoodVendingMachineClass`, like the `B` class of your example.

Let's have another class called `CatClass`, like the `A` class of your example.

The `FastFoodVendingMachineClass` class represents a vending machine that performs several operations, a.k.a "methods".

(Simplified) Class Diagram:

```
...................................................................
....+-----------------------------------------------------------+..
....|                          <<class>>                        |..
....|                FastFoodVendingMachineClass                |..
....+-----------------------------------------------------------+..
...................................................................
```

The `CatClass` represents a user that also perform several actions, a.k.a "methods".

(Simplified) Class Diagram:

```
...................................................................
....+-------------------------------------------------+............
....|                    <<class>>                    |............
....|                    CatClass                     |............
....+-------------------------------------------------+............
...................................................................
```

Now, the kitty, is a highly trained pet, that is hungry, and, wants to get some food,
from the machine. So, it gets money from its owner, and, walks to the machine,
inserts the money, selects a button, and gets its food.

Both objects / subjects described with classes performs several operations,
to themselves, or to others.

How will that look in a Sequence Diagram ?

Sequence Diagram:

```
................................................................................
.............+--------------+..............+-----------------------------+......
.............|   CatClass   |..............| FastFoodVendingMachineClass |......
.............+-------+------+..............+--------------+--------------+......
.....................|....................................|.....................
...................+-+-+................................+-+-+...................
......<<start>>....|   |................................|   |...................
..(*)=============>|   +---+............................|   |...................
...................|   |...|............................|   |...................
...................|   |...|..<<returns>>...............|   |...................
...............+===+   +<--+............................|   |...................
..............."...|   |................................|   |...................
....GetFood().."...|   |................................|   |...................
..............."...|   |..........InsertMoney().........|   |...................
...............+==>+   +===============================>+   +---+...............
...................|   |................................|   |...|...............
...................|   |..........<<returns>>...........|   |...|...............
...............+===+   +<-------------------------------+   |<--+...............
..............."...|   |................................|   |...................
.....Insert...."...|   |................................|   |...................
.....Money....."...|   |.....ReceiveMoney(Price)........|   |...................
.....(Price)...+==>+   +===============================>+   +---+...............
...................|   |................................|   |...|...............
...................|   |..........<<returns>>...........|   |...|...............
...............+===+   +<-------------------------------+   |<--+...............
..............."...|   |................................|   |...................
.....Select...."...|   |................................|   |...................
.Fishburguer()."...|   |.....SelectProduct(Option)......|   |.....Product.=.....
...............+==>+   +===============================>+   +---+.Release.......
...................|   |................................|   |...|.Product.......
...................|   |............Product.............|   |...|.(Option)......
...............+---+   +<-------------------------------+   |<--+...............
..<<returns>>..|...|   |................................|   |...................
...............|...|   |..........<<returns>>...........|   |...................
...............+-->+   +------------------------------->+   +---+.Change.=......
...................|   |................................|   |...|.Return........
......<<finish>>...|   |.............Change.............|   |...|.Option()......
..(O)<=============|   |<-------------------------------+   |<--+...............
...................|   |................................|   |...................
...................+-+-+................................+-+-+...................
.....................|....................................|.....................
.....................X....................................X.....................
................................................................................
```

And, the more detailed class diagrams:

```
...................................................................
....+-------------------------------------------------+............
....|                    <<class>>                    |............
....|                    CatClass                     |............
....+-------------------------------------------------+............
....| [+] bool: GetFood();                            |............
....| [+] void: InsertMoney(Currency Price);          |............
....| [+] void: SelectFishburguer();                  |............
....+-------------------------------------------------+............
...................................................................

...................................................................
....+-----------------------------------------------------------+..
....|                          <<class>>                        |..
....|                FastFoodVendingMachineClass                |..
....+-----------------------------------------------------------+..
....| [+] void: ReceiveMoney(Currency Price);                   |..
....| [+] void: SelectProduct(int Option);                      |..
....| [+] Product: ReleaseProduct(int Option);                  |..
....| [+] void: NotifyEmpty();                                  |..
....| [+] Currency: ReturnChange();                             |..
....+-----------------------------------------------------------+..
...................................................................
```

Compare the class diagrams, with the sequence diagram. Note that the arrows from one bar to another, means one object ("instance of a class") executes a method from another.

Also note that sometimes, the same object may call another method from the same object.

For example, the `FastFoodVendingMachineClass` class has a `SelectProduct` method that when is executed may execute the `ReleaseProduct` method. But, what if,
the kitty pressed an option where food run out ?

The `SelectProduct` method will execute something like the `NotifyEmpty` method instead,
like making a "Beep" sound, or turning on a light, in the same machine.

I like to add a `&lt;&lt;start&gt;&gt;` state, and a `&lt;&lt;finish&gt;&gt;` state to sequence diagrams, to make the diagram more clear, that is a sequence of operations, among several classes.

This is not very common, but, is valid.